# Проблема с поиском абсолютного пути XPath к элементам десктопного приложения

Tags: c#, xpath, uiautomation

Всем читающим доброго времени суток!

На работе дали задачу автоматизировать GUI десктопного приложения (название не привожу, исходя из условий о неразглашении) и сразу столкнулся с проблемой поиска **абсолютного пути** XPath к элементам приложения. Для автоматизации выбрал фреймворк Winium.Cruciatus.

Вот XPath с **относительным путем**, который работает и находит нужный мне элемент:

```
var TextBoxElement = win.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@ClassName = 'PasswordBox' and contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'поле')]"));
```

Вот XPath с **абсолютным путем**, который я попытался написать, но он не сработал, этот путь искал через WInAppUiRecorder:

```
var TextBoxElement = win.FindElement(By.XPath("/Pane[@Name=\"Рабочий стол\"][@ClassName=\"#32769\"]/Window[@Name=\"Наименование приложения\"][@ClassName=\"Window\"]/Tab[@ClassName=\"TabControl\"]/TabItem[@Name=\"Подключение\"][@ClassName\"TabItem\"]/Custom[@Classname=\"CredentialBoxControl\"]/Edit=\"PasswordBox\"]"));
```

Прикладываю скрин DOM-дерева в Inspect, с помощью которого ищу элементы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ОС**: Windows 7.
**Среда разработки**: Visual Studio 2015.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением проблемы. Поиск элемента по относительному пути очень долго отрабатывает.

Comment: Что означает "не сработал"? Просто не находит или выдаёт какую-то ошибку? Какую именно?

Comment: Синтаксические ошибки же в аболютном xpath: `/Window[=\"Наименование приложения\"]`, `/Edit=\"PasswordBox\"]`.

Comment: Не находит элемент, то есть в переменную TextBoxElement после поиска записывается null.

Comment: Пробовал и по другому путь прописывать: /Pane[@Name='Рабочий стол'][@ClassName='#32769']/Window[='Наименование приложения'][@ClassName='Window'].

Comment: `[='Наименование приложения']` - ошибка же: где имя атрибута/элемента перед знаком равно?

Comment: + пробовал прописывать тип элемента по-русски: /панель[@Name='Рабочий стол'][@ClassName='#32769']/окно[='Наименование приложения'][@ClassName='Window']. Так же в переменную записывается null.

Comment: Не вводите сразу весь длинный путь. Попробуйте сперва получить ссылку (не null) на рабочий стол. Потом ссылку на следующий элемент в иерархии и так далее.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, пропустил при оформлении. На самом деле [@Name='Наименование приложения']. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Пробовал получить ссылку на само приложение, но в общем все упирается в наименование типа элемента. Если вместо наименования указать выбор всех элементов * с заданными атрибутами, то ссылку получить удается без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за внимание! Остановился на решении прописывать абсолютно/относительный путь, например: `*[@ClassName = 'Window' and @Name = 'Быстрый поиск услуг']/*[@ClassName = 'TextBox' and @LocalizedControoType = 'поле']` и т.д.